# innerhtml result to a better format

Tags: javascript, html

I am very novice with coding, I just started learning about it a week ago.
To cut the story short, i have a code here.

```js
function lookup (){
 var mac_address = document.getElementById('mac_address');
 var resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
 if(mac_address.value.length<6){
  alert('Enter at least 6 characters!')
 }else{
  var lookUpAdress = '<object type="text/html" id="lookupresult" data="http://macvendors.co/api/jsonp/'+mac_address.value+'"></object>';
  resultDiv.innerHTML=lookUpAdress;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey w3-text-black w3-margin">
<div style="padding:0px;">
 <label>Enter mac address:</label>
 <input type="text" id="mac_address" />
 <input type="button" value="Lookup!" onclick="lookup();" />
 <div id="result" style="margin-top:10px;" class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey w3-text-black w3-margin">
 </div><!-- Result. -->
</div><!-- Input Box. -->
</div><!-- Container. -->
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the result of the Look Up and show it in a better format like : 
Company : 
Prefix : 
Address :

Takenote I'd be happy just to get the "Company."

TIA.

Comment: it's better to give us an example of a `MAC Adress` so we get the results quicker. And use `AJAX` to make your job done.

Comment: Use Ajax request to get the data from JSONP endpoint, once received the response you will be able to format the data in a way you want. You can use jQuery Ajax, the doc is available here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Sample MAC : 34:13:e8:1b:82:e4

I think the $.ajax ain't working for me.

Unless, you can suggest a script. I tried the one from macvendors.co but it ain't giving results(not working).

Answer (score 0):

Load jquery together with your html, make sure jquery is loaded otherwise you wont be able to use $.ajax and will have to go the javascript way. Also it is alot easier to use jquery than javascript to manupilate the dom. So if you are a beginner, first learn jquery then move on to javascript.

```
<script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Use the above one or any other. You can google jquery cdn.

Then add a script to the bottom of your html:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     GetMacAddress();
    });
function GetMacAddress(){
$.ajax({
       url:'http://macvendors.co/api/jsonp/34:13:e8:1b:82:e4',
       type:'get',
       success:function(data){
          // do something with data
          alert(data.result.company);
       },
       error:function(){
         console.log('oops');
       },
});
}
    </script>
```

This code will get you the result, change the code to suite your needs, i.e. display something in textbox

Comment: I believe this will run into a `blocked cross-origin` won't it?

Comment: i was focusing on explaining that jquery must be included in the html first before ajax can be used. Not sure about cross origins

Comment: Yeah did you try and run it? And no. It's pretty simple to do an XMLHTTP request without jquery

Comment: I guess the problem is with the site itself. That here is the error I'm getting:
`Failed to load https://macvendors.co/api/jsonp/34:13:e8:1b:82:e4: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: For example the `GitHub API` allows it. It returns a response when I request: `https://api.github.com/users/<username>`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would solve your problem but:

- You had to look up how to do it in non jQuery (or use jQuery)
- I couldn't get it to work with `https` connections

```js
$.getJSON('https://anyorigin.com/go?url=http%3A//macvendors.co/api/jsonp/34%3A13%3Ae8%3A1b%3A82%3Ae4&callback=?', function(data){
 console.log(data.contents);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You may read more about it here: 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/client-side-web-scraping-with-javascript-using-jquery-and-regex-5b57a271cb86